# catching SQLAlchemy exceptions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, exception

What is the upper level exception that I can catch SQLAlechmy exceptions with ?

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import exc
>>> dir(exc)
['ArgumentError', 'CircularDependencyError', 'CompileError', 'ConcurrentModificationError', 'DBAPIError', 'DataError', 'DatabaseError', 'DisconnectionError', 'FlushError', 'IdentifierError', 'IntegrityError', 'InterfaceError', 'InternalError', 'InvalidRequestError', 'NoReferenceError', 'NoReferencedColumnError', 'NoReferencedTableError', 'NoSuchColumnError', 'NoSuchTableError', 'NotSupportedError', 'OperationalError', 'ProgrammingError', 'SADeprecationWarning', 'SAPendingDeprecationWarning', 'SAWarning', 'SQLAlchemyError', 'SQLError', 'TimeoutError', 'UnboundExecutionError', 'UnmappedColumnError', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>>
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

From [the source](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/exc.py#L10):

> The base exception class is
>   `SQLAlchemyError`.

Comment: You may need to use two exception classes. `Exceptions which are raised as a result of DBAPI exceptions are all subclasses of DBAPIError.` http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError

Comment: @Wes: `DBAPIError` [is a subclass of](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/exc.py#L333) `StatementError` which in turn [is a subclass of](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/exc.py#L280) `SQLAlchemyError`. So, just catching `SQLAlchemyError` should be fine.

Answer (score 107):

To catch any exception SQLAlchemy throws:

```
from sqlalchemy import exc
db.add(user)
try:
  db.commit()
except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
  pass # do something intelligent here
```

See help(sqlalchemy.exc) and help(sqlalchemy.orm.exc) for a list of possible exceptions that sqlalchemy can raise.

Comment: Would make sense to put `db.add(user)` inside the `try` block as well.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your version of SQLAlchemy (e.g. 1.0.4), you may need to do a little more to get to the base-`SQLAlchemyError` class:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import exc
exceptions = exc.sa_exc

try:
    my_admin = user_models.User('space cadet', active=True)
    db.session.add(my_admin)
    db.session.commit()
except exceptions.SQLAlchemyError:
    sys.exit("Encountered general SQLAlchemyError.  Call an adult!")
```

this is because `sqlalchemy.orm.exc` now has the stanza:

```
"""SQLAlchemy ORM exceptions."""
from .. import exc as sa_exc, util
```

Comment: This is an issue with the way flask-ext-sqlalchemy is trying to wrap exceptions. If you're not using the Flask extension, you can catch the orm errors with base `SQLAlchemyError` from `sqlalchemy.exc` just fine...