# Why does the SQLAlchemy documentation put the add operation inside try/except without a flush operation?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to understand SQLAlchemy (1.4) and I can't quite put things together. I can find examples that put either `session.commit()` ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193670/catching-sqlalchemy-exceptions/4430982#4430982), [FAQ](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/sessions.html#this-session-s-transaction-has-been-rolled-back-due-to-a-previous-exception-during-flush-or-similar)) or `session.add()` ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52234206/825372), [session documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#framing-out-a-begin-commit-rollback-block)) inside `try`.

For me `add()` never raises an exception unless I manually call `flush()` as well.

My initial guess was that `autoflush` enabled means `add()` is automatically flushed and the following example from the [flushing documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#flushing) seems to suggest as much (otherwise why use *this* as an example?)

```py
with mysession.no_autoflush:
    mysession.add(some_object)
    mysession.flush()
```

but it makes no difference and reading on it seems that `autoflush` only affects query operations.

I can just put `commit()` inside `try`, but I'd appreciate if someone could help me understand why a decade old SO answer works for me while the official documentation doesn't. Am I missing some other configuration?

Comment: In the example in the docs, the try block is for the `commit()` that will be executed when leaving the `session.begin` context manager.